# Struts2 JQuery how to do onchange ajax

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

Let's say I have sj:autocompleter like this :

```
<sj:autocompleter  id="idDistributor" 
name="idDistributor" 
list="%{idDistributorList}"  label="ID
Distributor"  indicator="indicator" />
```

when the value is changed, I'd like to pass the detail value to other text field like this :

```
<sj:textfield label="Nama Distributor" id="namaDistributor" name="namaDistributor" required="true"/>
```

where its value will be retrieved from struts back bean (FormAction).

How I could do this?

Really thanks in advance.

Mr.K

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will send the autocompleter value to your action and set the value of `#namaDistributor` with the returned string:

```
$('#idDistributor').change(function(){
    // Make the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/back-bean.action',
        data: "autocompleterValue=" + $(this).val(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {    
            // Set the inputs from the json object            
            $('#namaDistributor').val(data.distributor);
            $('#namaPrice').val(data.price);
        }
    });
});
```

You can read more about the [$.ajax() method here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  The above json example assumes that your Action is creating a json object with the following format:

```
{"price": "123.40", "distributor": "XYZ Inc."}
```

You can read more about using json with Struts2 in [this article](http://www.zulutown.com/blog/2009/07/12/ajax-dynamic-content-with-struts2-jquery-and-json-plugin/).

Comment: Hi Pat, I'd like to pass the result value from back bean to #namaDistributor not directly from idDistributor value, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Not a problem.  I've updated the code to show how you'd update `#namaDistributor` from the result of the ajax call.

Comment: Awesome, it works...with little bit modification on back bean for returning the StreamResult not String. Pat, sorry for further question, if I want to modify multiple textfield after autocompleter onchange, how can I do this?, on the other word I need to return two value for two different field.

Thanks.

Comment: View my updates (again :) to see how you would do this using json.

Comment: awesome..awesome it works using json!!!, actually I'm quite new on JQuery, really thanks for your support.

Mr.K

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out.  Once you get past the initial learning curve, jQuery is pretty easy to use.

Comment: +1 for this answer..how can we pass two variables using json.can u please specifies struts.xml for that?

Comment: how can I set the json value returned here to another autocompleter or select box

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with onSelectTopics.

Subscribe a topic like this:

```
<script>
$.subscribe('autocompleteSelect', function(event, data) {
  var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
  $('#namaDistributor').val(ui.item.value);
});
</script>
```

and at it to your autocompleter

```
<sj:autocompleter  id="idDistributor" 
name="idDistributor" onSelectTopics="autocompleteSelect"
list="%{idDistributorList}"  label="ID
Distributor"  indicator="indicator" />
```

you can find an example for this in the [Struts2 jQuery Plugin Showcase](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)